# How to stop at first occurrence while replacing a multiline text

Tags: sed

I have a file `pom.xml`, which needs to have the version with a `SNAPSHOT` appended to it. At times, the `SNAPSHOT` is missing, which results in the build failing. I'm trying to replace it with `SNAPSHOT` if it doesn't exist.

Actual:

```
<artifactId>package1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

Desired:

```
<artifactId>package1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Since the `artifactId` is not going to be the same across all the projects, I tried to search for a pattern that starts from `</artifactId>` to `</version>` and replace it with the `SNAPSHOT` text added to it. This has resulted in replacing the text till the last `version` available in `pom.xml`.

I've tried the following:

```
cat pom.xml | sed ':a;N;$!ba;1,/<\/artifactId>/s/<\/artifactId><version>[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*<\/version>/<\/artifactId><version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT<\/version>/g'
```

(Not working at all as it's unable to find the end of line).

```
cat common-pom.xml | sed ':a;N;$!ba;0,/<\/artifactId>/s/<\/artifactId>.*<\/version>/<\/artifactId><version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT<\/version>/g'
```

(Is able to do the changes, but it's replacing all the text till the last `version` available in `pom.xml`).

How do I stop the replacement to the first occurrence in a multi line replacement?

Comment: Actually, what keeps you from just making the substitutions on the lines starting with `<version>`?

Comment: Since that there are so many <version> in the pom.xml and the replacement needs to be done at only one place, I can't replace all of them.

Comment: @jonathan-lefflet, I did go through the question mentioned by you. I was caught up with the extra line that needs to be handled explicitly. I couldn't get it through. Please reconsider the downvote as my question is slightly different from the one mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this should work:

```
sed -r '
    /<artifactId>/ {
        n
        s/(([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9])(<\/version>)/\1-SNAPSHOT\3/
    }
' infile
```

You read the complete file into sed before starting with replacements. This just looks for a line with `<artifactId>`, reads the next line (`n`) and makes the replacement there.

Also, instead of using `cat` to pipe to sed, you can just give the file to be processed as an argument to sed.

This works also without `-r`, but then all parentheses and braces would have to be escaped.

Example file:

```
<artifactId>package1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>           <-- should get SNAPSHOT
<artifactId>package1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  <-- already has SNAPSHOT
Somethingelse
<version>1.0.0</version>           <-- doesn't follow artifactId line
```

results in

```
<artifactId>package1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<artifactId>package1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
Somethingelse
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

Comment: Thanks, the given solution worked